# Power calculation in exponential survival model with varying follow-up duration

Tags: r, survival, statistical-power, clinical-trials

Suppose I have a clincal trial where I use an exponential survival model to compare the effects of two treatments. Patients are recruited over a time interval of two years. Ideally, I would have a constant maximal follow-up duration for all patients of, say, four years. However, in my case this is not possible, i.e. patients will have different maximal follow-up durations due to the two-year recruitment period.
Is there a way to consider this in the calculation of the power? 
Currently I use the `power.startify()` function from the [`powerSurvEpi()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/powerSurvEpi/index.html) package in R which assumes a constant study duration.

Answer (score 1):

Conducting a power estimate in a clinical study when patient recruitment occurs over time and follow-up periods fluctuate as a result can be tricky. In a survival analysis scenario, such as an exponential survival model, the variable follow-up time must be accounted for in the power analysis. As you noted, the `power.startify()` method in the `powerSurvEpi` package in R implies a constant study period, which may not be appropriate for your trial design.

**Possible approaches to consider are:**

- **Simulations**: Simulating the actual recruitment and follow-up procedure in simulation studies,  can provide a more accurate estimate of statistical  power.To evaluate power, you can simulate datasets under multiple circumstances (different effect sizes, changing follow-up lengths) and apply your exponential model to these datasets.
- **Piecewise Exponential Models**: These models can account for changes in the hazard rate over time, which is essential if you expect the treatment impact to vary over time. The model can be stratified based on the time of recruitment, allowing for varying hazard rates for different recruitment periods.
- **Cox Proportional Hazards Model with Time-Varying Covariates**: If the proportional hazards assumption holds true, a Cox model with time-dependent covariates could be used to account for the varying follow-up times.
  This method can account for individuals enrolled later in the study period having shorter follow-up times.
- **Accelerated Failure Time Model with Time-Varying Covariates:** This is a parametric survival model and may be appropriate if the proportional hazards assumption does not hold.
- **Changed Assumptions** You could also think about changing the assumptions in your current power calculation approach to adjust for varied follow-up. Instead of a single follow-up period, for example, utilise a mean or median follow-up time based on your recruitment strategy.